# Locking a text file while another child process writes to it

Tags: c, linux, fork, file-writing, file-locking

I implemented forked multiple clients in c and they are all supposed to write to a common file. This has failed so far since the information from these sockets is all messed up in the file destination.
This is my code

```
    FILE *Ufptr;
    Ufptr = fopen("Unsorted_busy_list.txt","a+");

    fprintf(Ufptr, "%s:%d\n",inet_ntoa(newAddr.sin_addr),ntohs(newAddr.sin_port));
    fclose(Ufptr);
```

I've been told that using fcntl and mutex lock onto the file could do, but am new to this and don't know how to implement this around the file writing process.
Any help

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7552451/can-multiple-processes-append-to-a-file-using-fopen-without-any-concurrency-prob

Comment: Most file locking in POSIX systems is 'advisory' and not 'mandatory'.  You'd need an inter-process mutex, not a within-process mutex (because you have processes courtesy of `fork()` and not threads).

Comment: Rather than a common file, you should consider using an Unix domain datagram socket pair (created to `int fd[2];` via `socketpair(AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM, 0, fd)`), possibly one socket pair per child. An Unix domain datagram socket preserves message boundaries (so each successful `send()` is received using exactly one `recv()`. You can even send/receive binary messages, say pairs of `struct in_addr` or `struct in6_addr`s. No locking needed, and a simple non-blocking `select()`/`poll()`+`recv()` loop in the parent can receive from multiple clients without issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment, if the parent consumes the output from the children, it is usually easier to use an Unix domain datagram socket pair (or pair per child process). Unix domain datagram sockets preserve message boundaries, so that each datagram successfully sent using `send()` is received in a single `recv()`. You can even send data as binary structures. No locks are needed.  If you use a socket pair per child, you can easily set the parent side to nonblocking, and use `select()` or `poll()` to read datagrams from all in a single loop.

---

Back to the question proper.

Here is an example implementation of `append_file(filename, format, ...)` that uses POSIX.1-2008 [`vdprintf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/vdprintf.3.html) to write to the file, using `fcntl()`-based advisory record locks:

```
#define  _POSIX_C_SOURCE  200809L
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

int append_file(const char *filename, const char *format, ...)
{
    struct flock  lock;
    va_list       args;
    int           fd, cause;

    /* Sanity checks. */
    if (!filename || !*filename)
        return errno = EINVAL;

    /* Open the file for appending. Create if necessary. */
    fd = open(filename, O_WRONLY | O_APPEND | O_CREAT, 0666);
    if (fd == -1)
        return errno;

    /* Lock the entire file exclusively.
       Because we use record locks, append_file() to the same
       file is NOT thread safe: whenever the first descriptor
       is closed, all record locks to the same file in the process
       are dropped. */
    lock.l_type = F_WRLCK;
    lock.l_whence = SEEK_SET;
    lock.l_start = 0;
    lock.l_len = 0;
    if (fcntl(fd, F_SETLKW, &lock) == -1) {
        cause = errno;
        close(fd);
        return errno = cause;
    }

    if (format && *format) {
        cause = 0;
        va_start(args, format);
        if (vdprintf(fd, format, args) < 0)
            cause = errno;
        va_end(args);
        if (cause) {
            close(fd);
            return errno = cause;
        }
    }

    /* Note: This releases ALL record locks to this file
             in this process! */
    if (close(fd) == -1)
        return errno;

    /* Success! */
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int arg = 1;

    if (argc < 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [ -h | --help ]\n", argv[0]);
        fprintf(stderr, "       %s FILENAME STRING [ STRING ... ]\n", argv[0]);
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
    }

    for (arg = 2; arg < argc; arg++)
        if (append_file(argv[1], "%s\n", argv[arg])) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s.\n", argv[1], strerror(errno));
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

If all writers use the above `append_file()` to append to the file, it is safe to rename the file at any point. (Just note that it is possible for one or more processes to do a final appending to the file *after* the rename, if they were waiting for the record lock to be released during the rename.)

To truncate the file, first take an exclusive lock on it, and then call `ftruncate(fd, 0)`.

To read the file, take an `fcntl()`-based shared lock `F_RDLCK` (allowing other readers at the same time; or `F_WRLCK`, if you intend to "atomically" truncate the file after you've read the current contents), or you may see a partial final record at the end.

Comment: Thanks @Norminal Animal. But is this solution above also valid on linux?

Comment: @MikeM: Yes, it is. (I wrote and tested it on Linux, in fact.)

Comment: thanx @Norminal Animal